# SVG - get pixel color from <image> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Is it possible to get color or even pixel info from  in SVG ?

```
<svg id="ledse"  viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" height="100%"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" > 
   <image xlink:href="test.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px"/>
</svg>
```

This what I want to do:

[image]

Under image I have black dots. I need to put color on it from squares which ones are over dots. Any idea how to do this in SVG?

Comment: Copy the image to canvas via drawImage and read it off the canvas.

Comment: I edited what i need to do. I think it would be hard to mix dots position with canvas pixels positions. Also i want to move and resize image so positions of pixel/colors will be changing.